# How simplify two neested loops in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to simplify two neested for loops in python but I cant resolve this.
My code:

```py
head = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
temp = []
for array in head:
    for element in array:
        temp.append(element)
print(temp)
========OUTPUT========
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I try:

```py
head = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
temp = []
for array in head:
   temp += [element for element in array]
print(temp)
```

But only can simplify one loop

## EDIT: SOLUTION

Specific solution for my case by @serafeim:

```py
head = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print([element for array in head for element in array])
```

### Other solutions:

By anon

```py
from functools import reduce
head = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print(reduce(list.__add__, head))
```

By: @chepner

```py
from itertools import chain
head = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print([x for x in chain.from_iterable(head)])
```

By: @R-zu

```py
import numpy as np
head = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print(np.array(head).reshape(-1).tolist())
```

Comment: Nice question. see my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468777/5025009

Comment: @Prune this is not an exact duplicate. I suggest to remove it and leave the OP open

Comment: oh, thanks! it's solved my problem

Comment: @Prune reopen the OP asap

Comment: I found a new way in a forum. Importing `reduce` from standart lib `functools` can do `temp = reduce(list.__add__, head)`

Comment: I am posting here a solution since this questions is NOT a duplicate: `results = [element for array in head for element in array]` should do the trick in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already available from the `itertools` module.

```
from itertools import chain

temp = [x for x in chain.from_iterable(head)]
# or just temp = list(chain.from_iterable(head))
```

Answer (score 1):

A n-dimensional array is better than a list in some cases.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) 
print(x.reshape(-1))
print(x.reshape(-1).tolist())
```

Comment: It's print `[1 2 3 4]` but I want `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Conversion from list to numpy array is slow. Vectorized operations over numpy array is much faster than over a list. Pick the data structure/implementation that suits your use case. If you need lots of insertion/deletion operation, use list.